KOMA-Script Letter (v2) seems to ignore the specified margins
A letter I wrote fits on a page (US Letter) comfortably, but the closing part ("Respectfully yours") is still moved to the second page.
I tried replacing "Default Margins" with explicit settings:
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass scrlttr2
\begin_preamble
\listfiles
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Here you can modify the layout of your letter
%% Have a look at the KOMA script documentation
%% for details. Most commands are commented out
%% here (i.e. we use default settings)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% Load an *.lco style file (see KOMA documentation)
%\LoadLetterOption{DIN}%                          

%% THE CLASS OPTIONS
%% Remove preceeding '%' to uncomment an item
\KOMAoptions{%
firstfoot=false,
%,headsepline=true%            separate the header with a line on page >1
%,footsepline=true%             separate the footer with a line on page >1
%pagenumber=botcenter%   position of the page number (see docu)
%,parskip=false%          Use indent instead of skip (more options cf. docu)
fromalign=center%        alignment of the address
,fromrule=true%    separate the address with a line?
,fromphone=false%         print sender phone number
,fromfax=false%          print sender fax number
,fromemail=true%           print sender e-mail address
,fromurl=false%               print sender URL
%,fromlogo=true%         print a logo (position depends on fromalign)
%,addrfield=false%        print an address field?
,backaddress=false%  print the back address?
%,subject=afteropening,titled% alternative subject layout and position
%,locfield=narrow%      width of the (extra) location field
,foldmarks=true%      print foldmarks?
,twoside=false
%,numericaldate=true%  date layout
%,refline=wide%             layout of the refline
}

%% Customize Separators
%\setkomavar{placeseparator}{ -- }
\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{ $\cdot$ }
%\setkomavar{emailseparator}{ --> }
%\setkomavar{enclseparator}{ > }
%\setkomavar{faxseparator}{ --> }
%\setkomavar{phoneseparator}{ --> }
%\setkomavar{subjectseparator}{ >>> }

%% Customize fonts
%% Use LaTeX's standard font commands
%% Modify with \setkomafont or \addtokomafont
%% (see KOMA documentation)
%% \setkomafont{backaddress}{\rmfamily}
%\setkomafont{descriptionlabel}{}
%% \setkomafont{fromaddress}{\large}
%% \setkomafont{fromname}{\scshape}
%\setkomafont{pagefoot}{}
%\setkomafont{pagehead}{}
%\setkomafont{pagenumber}{}
%\setkomafont{subject}{}
%\setkomafont{title}{}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language ukrainian
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize letterpaper
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\leftmargin 1cm
\topmargin 1cm
\rightmargin 1cm
\bottommargin 1mm
\headheight 3cm
\headsep 1cm
\footskip 1cm
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style russian
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle fancy
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Name
Wombat the Magnificent
\end_layout

\begin_layout SenderAddress

\lang english
0 Privacy Drive
\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset

Newton, MA 02462
\end_layout

\begin_layout E-Mail

\lang english
sbu@example.com
\end_layout

\begin_layout Address
Random Chairman
\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Subject
Healing toothache by turning into a bird
\end_layout

\begin_layout Opening
Honorable Mister Chairman!
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
It has come to our attention, that birds are by their nature toothless and
 cannot have a toothache.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Please, investigate the possibility of alleviating the acute instances of
 such illness by turning the patient into a bird of his choice.
 Care should be taken, that the bird is flightless, lest there might be
 accidents of another sort.
\end_layout

\begin_layout EndLetter
Respectfully,
\end_layout

\begin_layout Signature
The Wombat
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document

but that didn't change anything. The letter is still rendered with very wide margins (2+ inches), and the bottom one is particularly large -- the text ends above the lower fold-mark, with the rest of the first page blank and the second page containing nothing but the closing.
How do I prevail upon LyX and/or TeX to fit it all on one page? Some preamble

Your Respectfully is set after \end{letter} and therefore behind the letter and therefore always on a new page. You should set it using \closing{…} and also set the signature variable at the beginning, because it is always set for the next letter (usually used at the next \closing{…}):
#LyX 2.4 created this file. For more info see https://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 620
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass scrlttr2
\begin_preamble
\listfiles
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Here you can modify the layout of your letter
%% Have a look at the KOMA script documentation
%% for details. Most commands are commented out
%% here (i.e. we use default settings)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% Load an *.lco style file (see KOMA documentation)
%\LoadLetterOption{DIN}%                          

%% THE CLASS OPTIONS
%% Remove preceeding '%' to uncomment an item
\KOMAoptions{%
firstfoot=false,
%,headsepline=true%            separate the header with a line on page >1
%,footsepline=true%             separate the footer with a line on page >1
%pagenumber=botcenter%   position of the page number (see docu)
%,parskip=false%          Use indent instead of skip (more options cf. docu)
fromalign=center%        alignment of the address
,fromrule=true%    separate the address with a line?
,fromphone=false%         print sender phone number
,fromfax=false%          print sender fax number
,fromemail=true%           print sender e-mail address
,fromurl=false%               print sender URL
%,fromlogo=true%         print a logo (position depends on fromalign)
%,addrfield=false%        print an address field?
,backaddress=false%  print the back address?
%,subject=afteropening,titled% alternative subject layout and position
%,locfield=narrow%      width of the (extra) location field
,foldmarks=true%      print foldmarks?
,twoside=false
%,numericaldate=true%  date layout
%,refline=wide%             layout of the refline
%,enlargefirstpage
}

%% Customize Separators
%\setkomavar{placeseparator}{ -- }
\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{ $\cdot$ }
%\setkomavar{emailseparator}{ --> }
%\setkomavar{enclseparator}{ > }
%\setkomavar{faxseparator}{ --> }
%\setkomavar{phoneseparator}{ --> }
%\setkomavar{subjectseparator}{ >>> }

%% Customize fonts
%% Use LaTeX's standard font commands
%% Modify with \setkomafont or \addtokomafont
%% (see KOMA documentation)
%% \setkomafont{backaddress}{\rmfamily}
%\setkomafont{descriptionlabel}{}
%% \setkomafont{fromaddress}{\large}
%% \setkomafont{fromname}{\scshape}
%\setkomafont{pagefoot}{}
%\setkomafont{pagehead}{}
%\setkomafont{pagenumber}{}
%\setkomafont{subject}{}
%\setkomafont{title}{}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children no
\language ukrainian
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto-legacy
\fontencoding auto
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_roman_osf false
\font_sans_osf false
\font_typewriter_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\float_placement class
\float_alignment class
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize letter
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_formatted_ref 0
\use_minted 0
\use_lineno 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\leftmargin 1cm
\topmargin 1cm
\rightmargin 1cm
\bottommargin 1mm
\headheight 3cm
\headsep 1cm
\footskip 1cm
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style russian
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tablestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\change_bars false
\postpone_fragile_content false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\docbook_table_output 0
\docbook_mathml_prefix 1
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Name
Wombat the Magnificent
\end_layout

\begin_layout SenderAddress

\lang english
0 Privacy Drive
\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset

Newton,
 MA 02462
\end_layout

\begin_layout E-Mail

\lang english
sbu@example.com
\end_layout

\begin_layout Signature

\lang english
The Wombat
\end_layout

\begin_layout Address
Random Chairman
\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Subject
Healing toothache by turning into a bird
\end_layout

\begin_layout Opening
Honorable Mister Chairman!
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
It has come to our attention,
 that birds are by their nature toothless and cannot have a toothache.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Please,
 investigate the possibility of alleviating the acute instances of such illness by turning the patient into a bird of his choice.
 Care should be taken,
 that the bird is flightless,
 lest there might be accidents of another sort.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Closing
Respectfully
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document



I've also deactivated fancyhdr, because using the package with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended and scrlttr2 also has it's own mechanism to set the page header and footer. See the manual for more information.
Sometimes it could be useful to additionally add option enlargefirstpage, i.e., when using option firstfoot=false. So I've added it (but commented it) to your preamble.
BTW: The default letter layout DIN.lco has not been made for letterpaper. Therefore using DIN.lco with letterpaper results in a warning message. See also the KOMA-Script manual for alternatives.
Note also: Some KOMA-Script options like twoside=false do recalculate the margins according to the typearea settings. So if they are used after \geometry, they will change the settings of \geometry again. To avoid this, you should either not use these options after \geometry or restore the geometry settings after setting those options. However in your case, not using twoside=false is easier, because it is already the default of scrlttr2. Without the option, you get:

(But IMHO the ugly result is a very good example, why you should not use such small margins.)
If you want to use such options, the IMHO best solution would be, to use them as class options instead of setting them in the document preamble using \KOMAoptions. For some options like fontsize or parskip this is also recommended by the author. In LyX you can set class options at Document → Settings → Document Class.
For more information about the options, please see the KOMA-Script manuals.

Thanks for the pointers, I did use the wrong type for the closing -- because the type-names are translated into Ukrainian confusingly :( It looks better now, but the margins are still too wide. And they are too wide in your version too -- much bigger than 1cm on the left and the right, for example... Is there a way to affect that?

See my note about using KOMA-Script options, which are changing the page layout together with geometry.

Apropos language confusion: If you write an English letter, just don't set the Language in the Document Settings to Ukrain but English and all the field names will be in English.

Regarding using special options -- is not it something, LyX should be doing for me? Or, at least, disable setting the margins -- when they are known to have no effect. Regarding translation: a) my original letter was in Ukrainian; b) the language of the interface is the same -- based on the $LANG -- regardless of the language of a particular document...

So, by explicitly setting the twoside=false -- through LyX GUI -- I "broke" the margins? That really is something, the app should be doing... Thanks for the clarifications.

You don't set twoside=false through the LyX GUI. You set it in the manual document preamble setting. LyX does not analyze the TeX code there. This differs from setting twoside or not via Document → Settings → Page Layout → Two-sided document. And sorry, but using LyX does not prevent you from reading package instructions. At least not, if you use TeX code with LyX.

Note by the way that cabohah's LyX file is in 2.4.x format and cannot be opened in 2.3.x versions. 2.4.0 is planned for released in the coming weeks.

@scottkosty, I noticed cabohah's usage of unreleased LyX, which hints at his being part of the development :-) Hence my complaints about the application...

@MikhailT. I'm not part of the LyX development. SuSE Tumbleweed already distributes LyX 2.4 RC4. So I've got this version with the Linux updates on the machine I've used for the testing your question and finding a solution. I'm even never using LyX for typesetting, but only for answering questions on TeX.SX. The software prevents me too much from really using and understanding all the great features of LaTeX. Your question is a good example of how LyX requires an additional understanding of how the LaTeX code it produces works. Sometimes more complicated than using LaTeX directly.

@MikhailT. You might want to join lyx-users, and if you really want to blame the people responsible for LyX's bugs, let us know at lyx-devel ;)

I don't really want to blame you. Just occasionally :)
